# Undefined method for ri inside of IRB

Tags: ruby

Inside of the interactive ruby console if i type ri then i get an undefined method error, do i explicitly have to install documentation somewhere to get this to work?

```
irb(main):015:0* ri --help
NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:295
irb(main):016:0> ri Array
NoMethodError: undefined method `ri' for main:Object
    from (irb):16
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:295
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably do not want to do that. What you should be doing is exiting to the shell (or preferably, open a new terminal tab or screen session) and running ri separately, which is a program, from there. If you really, really, want to do what you're doing, you can always use backticks to run `ri --help`, or any other shell command.

> irb(main):015:0* `ri --help`

Comment: I feel like a complete newb for this question...wow. Good call %x{} works as well. On a related note, how do you make the back quotes on a keyboard? `

Comment: backticks for me are the key below escape

Comment: imo answer from Nakilon is the best answer: '--help' and it will invoke ri, without introducing any dependencies like ori

Answer (score 4):

In fact [ORI](http://github.com/dadooda/ori) gem can bring RI to your IRB console and give some more neat class exploration functions.

[Watch intro screencast](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXVVYuXpH).

#### Setup (`~/.irbrc`)

```
require "rubygems"
require "ori"
```

#### Request RI on a Class

```
Array.ri
String.ri
[].ri
"".ri
5.ri
```

#### Request RI on a Method

```
String.ri :upcase
"".ri :upcase
[].ri :sort
Hash.ri :[]
```

#### Request Interactive Method List

```
String.ri //
"".ri //
"".ri /case/
"".ri /^to_/
User.ri /^validates_/
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just `--help`:

```
irb(main):040:0> --help

Enter the method name you want to look up.
You can use tab to autocomplete.
Enter a blank line to exit.

>> Array
←[0m←[1;32mArray < Object←[m

(from gem backports-1.18.2)
------------------------------------------
```

To return into IRB, I pressed `Crtl+C`, but there probably is some some quit-command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ri` command has been deprecated. `irb` recommends to use `show_doc` instead, like the following:

```
irb(main):009:0> show_doc String#upcase



= String#upcase

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  upcase(*options) -> string

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns a string containing the upcased characters in self:

  s = 'Hello World!' # => "Hello World!"
  s.upcase           # => "HELLO WORLD!"

The casing may be affected by the given options; see {Case
Mapping}[doc/case_mapping_rdoc.html].

Related: String#upcase!, String#downcase, String#downcase!.
```